# What is best way to get and play Age of Mythology on Mac?

Tags: windows, macbook-pro, games

I have a 15 inch 1st gen MacBook Pro retina with windows 7 installed using boot camp and I would like to get the game Age of Mythology (with expansion) which I never had. What would be the best way to get the game and play it? For example, would it be best/possible to buy the windows version and play it on the 64 bit window 7 portion of my computer.

Note: Not sure if this question is better in Ask Different or Arqade. Will move question if prompted.

Thanks ahead of time for any advice.

UPDATE

I would like to get the game at a reduced price since it is so old so paying the full price for the OS X version is not preferred but will be considered.

UPDATE

And I would like the Titans expansion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being patient and did not make any purchases until recently when Age of Mythology: Extended Edition was released on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/266840/). It includes the Titans expansion and is likely to have more content added like what was done for Age of Empires II on Steam.

I do have to boot into Windows to play but it runs really well (graphics look awesome) through Steam.

Answer (score 1):

I would try PlayOnMac, it's an easy-to-use wrapper for a program called WINE which basically replicates all the Windows code a normal win32 application needs to run. They have a database on their website of games that work on it, you might try there.

Answer (score 0):

That game is available on Windows and OS X - you can buy either the windows or os x version and use either, I would suggest OS X if you'd prefer not to have to boot windows to play it. Your machine will be fine to play it!

However if you want absolutely the best framerates windows tends to be faster for games.

Comment: I was really intrigued by Amazon's offer of the windows version for under $10 but will do more research on where to buy OS X version.

Comment: I seriously doubt a modern Mac couldn't pull the same refresh rates as any PC on a 10 year-old game.

Comment: I remember why I was strongly considering Windows. It seems that the Titans Expansion was never released for Mac. Correct me if I am wrong.